# Support for Opera mini/Pocket PC

Tags: feature-request, opera

Currently trying to use the site(s) on my phone, which runs Opera on Windows Mobile 6.1. Actually looks OK. And if this comes through then question submitting works! But I just tried to upvote someone's answerr on both SO and here, and that doesn't work. Any plans to improve support for this browser? As a user of it, anything I can do to help if so?

**Further observations**

The [email validation problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5391/invalid-email-problem) I encountered is also down to Opera mini. It's fine now I'm in work on a proper PC.

Answer (score 1):

Opera mini [doesn't support AJAX](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-support-in-opera-mini-4/), the key to the entire voting process, as well as commenting etc. I personally do not feel they should go through the effort of making these features degrade nicely, since it is a lot of extra work for a very limited audience.

Stack Overflow was and always will be best suited for a modern day browser. That isn't to say it doesn't work on mobile browsers, but you shouldn't expect to have the same user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that Opera/WinCE/iPhone/what-have-you-platform tweaks don't really belong in *the* StackOverflow codebase.  Instead, this need should be served by third-party apps built using the (hopefully) forthcoming API.

For one, the experience would be a lot nicer.  There's also not much point in the developers working to support such a niche case, when I'm sure plenty of people will be willing to gin up clients for their favorite platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mini supports some Ajax, and works fine on the Stack sites. I've been commenting, answering, voting, tagging, etc, quite happily with it for over a week :)

Comment: On what phone? I'm totally blocked.

Comment: Sadly, so am I now. I can't get to any of the Stack sites via Mini except by using an additional proxy - it's been like this for almost 2 weeks

Answer (score 0):

I can vote on questions and answers (but not on comments), view vote splits, and vote to close questions with Opera mini on my BlackBerry, but I cannot post answers or comments. Ian's [point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5390/support-for-opera-mini-pocket-pc/9432#9432) is valid, but it'd be nice to have at least mid-90s "submit, next page" functionality on mobile browsers.