# Notifications considering valid e-mail address to be invalid

Tags: bug, status-norepro, email, validation

For the question I just submitted, I was unable to get notification e-mails because the system said my e-mail address was invalid. It isn't. It's a `.us` domain, though — could that be the issue?

Comment: its cuz SO hates opera mini.

Comment: You're totally right - it works here! It's another Opera mini compatibility issue. I'll rollback and add to my other question.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a logical assumption. I wouldn't be surprised if the email validation is a bit skimpy as far as what domains it allows.

Comment: I actually *would* be surprised.  Jeff knows how to validate an email address.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000214.html

Comment: @BilltheLizard - true, but Jeff doesn't write all the code, and most of us that do are idiots so, ya know.